# What is the Dragon Book for Rootkits on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, reference, linux-kernel, rootkit

I recently came across this book called **[The Rootkit Aresenal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598220616)** by Bill Blunden that gives a detailed (I mean it!) description of the basics underlying rootkits and also goes about on how to design them for Windows (so it requires some basic understanding of IA32-internals). Because I concentrate mostly on Linux-centric security, I can only use the book to gain basics but not anything related to the Linux kernel. Can anyone please suggest a Dragon book of Rootkits for Linux that will give me some ***hands-on experience***?

Just in case someone is about to ask me this question:

> "Why are you looking at rootkits?
>   Isn't that bad?"

Someone on slashdot once said:

> How can we implement security if we
>   don't understand the ways we can be
>   attacked?

Just to give an idea of what I am looking for: **It is enough if the Table of Contents of the reference looks something like the following only replaced with Linux rootkits instead of Windows.**

[The Rootkit Arsenal Table of Contents](http://books.google.com/books?id=5Cs46M9FV0sC&pg=PR5&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Linux is too cool for rootkits.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: +1 I agree. Trying to make the cool look hotter :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any books that have a focus on rootkits for Linux. I think you'll have more luck (and probably better material) by reading the [phrack zine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrack) instead, for example. There's a book about BSD rootkits so I guess you can adapt the *ideas* from one to the other (syscall interception, hooking with DRs, etc). The concepts are the same, just implementation differs, but you can find the source code for several good rootkits for linux online (suckit, etc) to use as reference. In phrack there's even a basic framework for a DR-based rootkit.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't focus on root kits I've found the excellent [Hacking Exposed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0071613749/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=alexsadveonth-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=0071613749) books give a lot of detail at various exploits. It's a multi-platform book and also looks at things like web-app security. However the Linux coverage is pretty reasonable.